# Is there a way to conver a LinkedList<String[]> to String[][]?

Tags: java, arrays, list

As the title says i wannt convert a LinkedList to String[][], and i don't know how.

```
LinkedList<String[]> list;
String[][] arrayStrings;

//What i tried, but doesn't work
arrayStrings = list.toArray(new String[list.size()][list.size()]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't provide the sizes of the contained arrays. You either don't provide an argument at all:

```
arrayStrings = list.toArray();
```

...or you provide an array with enough room:

```
arrayStrings = list.toArray(new String[list.size()][]);
```

The arrays within the outer array will be the **same** arrays that are in the list.

Example ([live copy](http://ideone.com/HQNg9Z)):

```
LinkedList<String[]> list = new LinkedList<String[]>();
list.add(new String[] { "a", "b" });
list.add(new String[] { "c", "d" });
list.add(new String[] { "e", "f" });

String[][] arrayStrings;

arrayStrings = list.toArray(new String[list.size()][]);
for (var entry : arrayStrings) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(entry));
}
System.out.println(arrayStrings[0] == list.get(0)); // true
```

Output:

```
[a, b]
[c, d]
[e, f]
true
```

Comment: Note that `list.toArray(new String[0][])` will work just fine.  A zero length array is a miniscule allocation.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a `Stream<String[]>` out of the `LinkedList<String[]>` and use the `toArray(IntFunction<A[]> generator)` to convert it to a 2 dimensional String array:

```
List<String[]> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add(new String[]{"foo", "bar"});
list.add(new String[]{"foo", "baz"});
String[][] arr = list.stream().toArray(String[][]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
```

Output:

```
[[foo, bar], [foo, baz]]
```

The `generator` is a function which produces a new array of the desired                  type and the provided length.

The above constructor reference can be explicitly expressed as a lambda:

```
String[][] arr = list.stream().toArray(len -> new String[len][]);
```

the `len` is the length of the resulting array.

Comment: Why would you want a `Stream` in the middle when `List` already has its own `toArray`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder What you said is logical, but I showed a way where I am not providing the size of the resulting array explicitly. :)